# Find the range of values for which the system can be approximated as a harmonic oscillator

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

I have been recently reworking on the harmonic oscillators in order to transition to quantum mechanics. I have, however a rather simple question. For the small angle approximation, how I can accurately deduce the range of values for which the differential equation converges. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a particular oscillatory system – a pendulum, perhaps – in mind? What do you mean by *convergence* of the differential equation?

Comment: I mean, for what range of values, the small angle approximation works.

Comment: Thank you. And the answer to my first question?